# Flutter - Add maps to a map

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose there are two maps.

```
Map map01 = {
  'name': 'Peter',
  'age': 30,
}

Map map02 = {
  'name': 'Mark',
  'age': 25,
}
```

And there's another map called `Map map1`.

I need to add these map01 and map02 to map1.

i. e.

```
Map map1 = {
  map01: {
    'name': 'Peter',
    'age': 50,
  },
  map02: {
    'name': 'Mark',
    'age': 25,
  },
}
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: can we create a list with `map01` and `map02` 1st? does it have to be variable name?

Comment: You mean create an empty list and add those two maps to list? Here's the thing I need to update value in a list of maps. That's seem to be impossible. So that's why I'm trying to add maps to map.

Comment: based on your map struct, try my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key isn't getting from variable name. It is generating from `map${(i + 1).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}`.

You can do something like this

```dart
    Map map01 = {
      'name': 'Peter',
      'age': 30,
    };

    Map map02 = {
      'name': 'Mark',
      'age': 25,
    };

    final myMaps = [map01, map02];
    final result = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < myMaps.length; i++) {
      final k = "map${(i + 1).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}";
      result.addAll({k: myMaps[i]});
    }
    print(result);
    //{map01: {name: Peter, age: 30}, map02: {name: Mark, age: 25}}
```

Comment: Hey can't we define a name Peter, Mark instead of map01, map02? Values inside of list?

Comment: in that case, we can create another list of names, and set them as key

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [Map](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/Map-class.html)